# C# Image Resize Math Issue

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

So I have a simple bit of code that re-sizes my profile images as they are consumed, problem is, the C# code isn't working the way I expected...

Here's the bit of code inside of the Controller Action Method for the Index View, where I'm doing this...

```
    string fullFileName = HttpContext.Server.MapPath(profile.ProfilePhotoPath);
    System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(fullFileName);
    int width = img.Width;
    int height = img.Height;

    float reductionPercentage = 0F;

    if (width >= height)
    {
        reductionPercentage = (282 / width);
    }
    if (width < height)
    {
        reductionPercentage = (337 / height);
    }

    int newWidth = (int)Math.Round(width * reductionPercentage);
    int newHeight = (int)Math.Round(height * reductionPercentage);

    ViewBag.newWidth = newWidth;
    ViewBag.newHeight = newHeight;
```

Every part of this works perfectly, except when it hits the "reductionPercentage = ***"

If the image is smaller or the same size, the reductionPercentage does exactly as it should and assign the value 1 to the reductionPercentage, however, if the image is larger, it's like it doesn't do the math at all, it always spits out 0 as the value for the reductionPercentage...

Any ideas, what could I possibly doing wrong?

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(282 / width)` and `(337 / height)` are [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html) - when the denominator is larger than the numerator, you will get `0` as a result.

Make one of the division participants a float to ensure floating point division.

```
if (width >= height)
{
    reductionPercentage = (282f / width);
}
if (width < height)
{
    reductionPercentage = (337f / height);
}
```

Comment: This code fails to compile; `282.0` and `337.0` are `double` literals and can't be implicitly converted to `float`.

Comment: Is there any reason to be using float in this day and age?

Answer (score 2):

Because `282`, `337`, `width`, and `height` are all integers, the `/` operator performs an integer division, truncating any fractional part of the result. Use `282f` and `337f` instead:

```
if (width >= height)
{
    reductionPercentage = 282f / width;
}
else
{
    reductionPercentage = 337f / height;
}
```

The `f` suffix signals that the number is a `float` instead of an `int`, so that a floating-point division is performed.